# Xargs stdout to file redirection appending file indefinitely

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, xargs

I have a problem with redirecting output from xargs namely I do something like:

```
find . -mmin -10 | xargs grep  mypattern > greping
```

This will keep writing to file indefinitely (I have waited until file reached around 25GB ) but when I change it to add pipe to grep at the end I will get proper results ( around 25 kB file ):

```
find . -mmin -10 | xargs grep  mypattern | grep 2013-07-11 > greping
```

What am I missing here and why does `xargs` in first code snippet keep writing to file ?

Bash version `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Works for me. What is your pattern? Please post the exact code.

Comment: @choroba My pattern is just a literal like `90001`, no regex, no `*` etc.

Comment: Maybe there are too many files or matches. What happens if you change `2013-07-11` to `2013` only?

Comment: Nothing change then. Anyway there is a problem with first piece of code not the second. The second works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Change redirected file from `>greping` to `>../greping` or `>/tmp/greping`.

Basically, output file should not be in current directory or any of its subdirectory.

Or try:

```
find . -mmin -10 | grep -Fx -v './greping' | xargs grep  mypattern > greping
```